# Should I add FDGuixWaitCursor to my apps using FireDAC?

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

We converted a large application suite from another database layer to FireDAC. The (Win32) programs currently do not implement a `FDGuixWaitCursor`, and the legacy code has calls to 'push', change and 'pop' the screen cursor.

Should I add `FDGuixWaitCursor` to my 'base' datamodule for any important/technical reason?
The documentation [Preparing a FireDAC Application for Run Time](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Preparing_a_FireDAC_Application_for_Run_Time) does not really answer that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily. The [**TFDGUIxWaitCursor**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.UI.TFDGUIxWaitCursor) component makes sense to use if you wanted to setup the cursor, handle cursor changing events or include the project type implementation by setting up the [**Provider**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.UI.TFDGUIxComponent.Provider) property. Nothing more at this time (Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo).

If you don't need any of this, you can just include **FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait** module into a VCL project, **FireDAC.FMXUI.Wait** into an FMX project, or **FireDAC.ConsoleUI.Wait** into a console project.

It's worth adding that FireDAC includes all the necessary modules automatically for its design time created components (so one of them is most likely included in your data module).

Comment: Correct, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait has automagically been included in one of my uses lists.